# UIButton isn't clickable on ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'm trying to add a UIButton programmatically onto my Scroll View. The button pops up on the screen, but it's not clickable...

Here's my code (viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlert:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Enter app" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    self.view.backgroundColor = COLOR_BG;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;

    CGRect scrollFrame;
    scrollFrame.origin.x = 0;
    scrollFrame.origin.y = 0;
    scrollFrame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width + 500;
    scrollFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height + 500;

    self.scrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame] autorelease];

    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = COLOR_BG;

    self.scrollView.bounces = YES;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.exclusiveTouch = YES;

    _scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    _scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
    self.slideImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    int rows = 8;


    int total_count = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < total_count;i++) {
        ImageRenderView *imageView = [[ImageRenderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * (SIZE+LEFT_EDGE_OFSET), 0, SIZE + LEFT_EDGE_OFSET, SIZE * rows)];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [self.slideImages addObject:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }


    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH_OF_SCROLL_PAGE, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

    self.gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.gradient.frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
    self.gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0] CGColor], nil];
    self.gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.1, 0.5);
    self.gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.9, 0.5);



    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(WIDTH_OF_IMAGE*2,0,WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];


    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(scrollView1:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [self.scrollView.layer addSublayer:self.gradient];
    [self makePerspective];
    self.scrollView.alpha = 0.0;

    ////

    CC_DIRECTOR_END();


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB8 color buffer, and a depth buffer f 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];


    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*)[CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    // Display Milliseconds Per Frame
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // 3D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    UINavigationController *navController_ = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_] autorelease];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [director_ setDelegate:nil];


    [self.view addSubview:navController_.view];

    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:YES];
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];

    movingBlockVC = [[MovingBlockContainer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [movingBlockVC view];

    CGRect old = movingBlockVC.view.frame;



    [self.view addSubview:movingBlockVC.view];
    movingBlockVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(-old.size.width, -old.size.height, old.size.width, old.size.height);
    movingBlockVC.view.hidden = YES;

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:movingBlockVC.view];

    director_.view.hidden = YES;

}
```

Can someone help me fix this? Or just explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you logged in showalert() method?. How you are telling that it's not clickable .Set backgroundcolor for scrollview's and check button is papearing above scrollview ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but looks like you add the button to your view, and then you add scrollview to your view on top of the button; which means that any touch event will end up in the scroll view not the button.

if my assumption is correct, you should add the button to the scrollview after it's initiated and configured.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in `scrollView1:`? If that has animations, then that is likely your problem.

Have a look at the animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` and see if that will help you.

Comment: Yes, the scroll view has an animation. Actually this one: https://github.com/indideveloper/MKMovingBlockAnimation

Comment: I didn't read through all of the MKMovingBlockAnimiation code, but most animations moves an "image" of the button, rather than the button itself. Obviously the animated image does not respond to touches like the actual `UIButton`.

Comment: Ok, so what do you suggest I should do?